# H2 Database: How can you do a point query with a TIMESTAMP ? Cannot find anything senerio that works

Tags: h2

How can you do a point query with a TIMESTAMP ?

I have a table with a TIMESTAMP column.  It is not the primary key, but for all practical purposes will be unique per row. 
The TIMESTAMP column may ( does not always ) contain nano seconds of precision.

If I run the query... "SELECT NAME, MSG_TS FROM CDS_HISTORY WHERE MSG_TS < '2014-06-20 21:36:43' "  I get ( results are correct as I would expect )...

```
Results: name=[1687] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.485]
Results: name=[1686] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.47]
Results: name=[1685] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.455]
Results: name=[1684] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.441]
Results: name=[1683] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.426]
Results: name=[1682] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.412]
Results: name=[1681] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.397]
Results: name=[1680] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.381]
Results: name=[1679] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.366]
Results: name=[1678] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.35]
Results: name=[1677] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.335]
Results: name=[1676] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.32]
Results: name=[1675] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.306]
Results: name=[1674] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.289]
Results: name=[1673] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.268]
Results: name=[1672] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.247]
Results: name=[1671] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.147]
Results: name=[1670] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.127]
Results: name=[1669] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.111]**
Results: name=[1668] msg_ts=[2014-06-20 21:36:42.057]
```

However, Using one row from the result set for a point query...
 "SELECT * FROM CDS_HISTORY WHERE MSG_TS = '2014-06-20 21:36:42.111' "   ->  0 rows...

"SELECT * FROM CDS_HISTORY WHERE MSG_TS = '2014-06-20 21:36:42.111000' "   ->  0 rows...

"SELECT * FROM CDS_HISTORY WHERE MSG_TS = '2014-06-20 21:36:42.111000000' "   ->  0 rows...

The casting and format functions in H2 mention that *java.text.SimpleDateFormat* is used so I do not believe I can use them when nano seconds are involved. 
( This example does not require nano seconds but I still have had no joy )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

The problem was a bug in H2 version 1.4.178 (beta), which was used originally. The bug was fixed in version 1.4.179 (still beta).

**Additionally**

How do you format the output ("Results: name=...")? You need to print the nanoseconds part. Yes, you can't use SimpleDateFormat as it doesn't support nanoseconds, but toString() and "cast(.. as varchar)" should work, see below.

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:");
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("select ?, cast(? as varchar)");
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(1);
ts.setNanos(123456789);
prep.setTimestamp(1, ts);
prep.setTimestamp(2, ts);
ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
System.out.println(ts);
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  I have no problem printing or seeing the TIMESTAMP with or without nano seconds.  What can not do is get a query to return the correct row when the where clause tries to equate to a single TIMESTAMP value.  Ranges work fine. But given a known TIMESTAMP from a range query I cannot select a specific row.  it does not return any results.

Comment: There was a problem in version 1.4.178 that was fixed with the very latest version, maybe it's that? If not, I would need a reproducible test case (in the form of my test case above).